# Starttime value is not correct and adding UTC time according to TimeZone on Top of what is at the backend field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

In actual code below in view section I am getting FormattedStartTime value at least 4 hours more than what it should be. Like if actual value is 3 p.m. then it is showing 19:00 instead of 15:00. At backend, field value is 3 p.m. and rather than displaying 15:00 on frontend view, it is displaying 19:00.

I think that it is converting backend field value into UTC time first according to TimeZone and then displaying that UTC time on front end. How can I fix this issue?? 
How can I convert any front end time which is in UTC according to my time zone, back to actual value according to my time zone?? My time zone is EST.

How it can work universally?? People could be sitting in any timezone.

After I debug the Code Start date is coming as 4/13/2017 7:00:00 PM and FormattedStartTime is coming as 19:00.

Model Class:

```
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

public string FormattedStartTime => StartDate?.ToString("HH:mm");

public bool HideTimestamp { get; set; }
```

Razor View:

```
if (!Model.HideTimestamp)
{
<span>@Model.FormattedStartDate @Model.FormattedStartTime</span>
}
```

Comment: 7:00pm *IS* 19:00.

Comment: Actual answer is 15:00 (3 p.m.) and not 19:00. I am getting the time (19:00) which is local time zone time selected (EST which is 15:00) + UTC time from EST time Zone (which is 4 hours more) and that adds up to 19:00. How can I get rid of UTC time??

Comment: You would need to go back to 1879 and stop Sir Sanford Fleming from [proposing a worldwide system of time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#Worldwide_time_zones).